# Support to landscape for one UIViewController in a portrait mode app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

My app has 4 views with this sequence:

**View Controller (VC1) -> 1 Navigation Controller -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4**

I want VC4 to support landscape mode and VC1, VC2 & VC3 have to be in portrait mode.

My deployment target is 7.1, so it has to support iOS 7 & 8.

I can't make VC4 work for only landscape mode. I set the whole app to support portrait and landscape but I can't prevent V1->VC3 to rotate to landscape.

**Only iPhone support**

Comment: Code for Swift and Obj-C: http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/

Comment: @rokjarc thanks so much ... that tutorial woks as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can allow app all orientations, and in View Controller specify needed orientations. In iOS 8 yo maybe needed override NavigationController for that.